# Configuring a package executable (.exe) in conda environment on windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, conda, vpython

I am using a package written in Python 2.7 ( not updated). This package has Vpython 2.7 - 5.74 as one of the dependencies. I couldn't find this version either with pip or conda. I found a .exe file of this version (2.7-5.74) of Vpython. How do I configure the .exe file on my conda environment?

I am using anaconda2 on windows.

Higher versions of Vpython doesn't work with the package.

Comment: Have you seen https://anaconda.org/vpython/vpython ?

Comment: yes, But Vpython 2.7 - 5.74  is unavailable.

Comment: _yes, But Vpython 2.7 - 5.74 is unavailable._ You're right, that's strange. I thought there would be at least a few versions of the package in that range, since versions 2.* and 7.* are available. It's the same thing with pypi. _I found a .exe file of this version (2.7-5.74) of Vpython._ Could the exe be an installer? Have you tried running it?

Comment: Indeed '.exe' is an installer. I was wondering how to have it in a specific conda environment and not a system-wide installation. That was my query.

Comment: Ah alright, I see. I'm not entirely sure then, do the vpython docs mention anything relevant when it comes to installation?

Answer (score 0):

Support of VPython 6 ended in Jan. 2016. See vpython.org for up-to-date information.

Comment: Thank you very much, Bruce.